# The App's BLoC is not working as expected

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I have created a bloc for the setting screen as follows.

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:qr_scanner/shared_pref_manager.dart';


part 'app_preferences_event.dart';
part 'app_preferences_state.dart';

class AppPreferencesBloc extends Bloc<AppPreferencesEvent, AppPreferencesState> {
 late bool sound;
 late bool vibrate;

 AppPreferencesBloc() : super(AppPreferencesStateInitial()) {
   _loadDefaultSettings();

   on<PlaySoundPrefEvent>((event, emit) {
     sound = !sound;
     SharedPrefManager().setSoundSetting(sound);
     emit(PlaySoundPrefState(sound));
   });

  on<VibratePrefEvent>((event, emit) {
    vibrate = !vibrate;
    SharedPrefManager().setVibrationSetting(vibrate);
    emit(VibratePrefState(vibrate));
  });
}

  _loadDefaultSettings() async {
    sound = await SharedPrefManager().getSoundSetting() ?? true;
    vibrate = await SharedPrefManager().getVirationSetting() ?? true;
  }
}
```

The following are events.

```
part of 'app_preferences_bloc.dart';

sealed class AppPreferencesEvent extends Equatable {
  const AppPreferencesEvent();

  @override
    List<Object> get props => [];
  }

class PlaySoundPrefEvent extends AppPreferencesEvent {}

class VibratePrefEvent extends AppPreferencesEvent {}
```

The following is the state class.

```
part of 'app_preferences_bloc.dart';

sealed class AppPreferencesState extends Equatable {
  const AppPreferencesState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

final class AppPreferencesStateInitial extends AppPreferencesState {}

final class PlaySoundPrefState extends AppPreferencesState {
  final bool sound;

  PlaySoundPrefState(this.sound);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [sound];
}

final class VibratePrefState extends AppPreferencesState {
  final bool vibrate;

  VibratePrefState(this.vibrate);

  @override
    List<Object> get props => [vibrate];
}
```

So in the setting screen I am using this bloc to read/write app's setting set by user.

```
    BlocSelector<AppPreferencesBloc, AppPreferencesState, bool>(
      selector: (state) {
        return (state is VibratePrefState) ? state.vibrate : true;
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return _getListTile(
            title: Constants.vibrarion,
            subtitle: Constants.vibrarionSubtitle,
            leadingIcon: Icons.vibration,
            trailing: Checkbox(
              value: state,
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
            action: () {
              context.read<AppPreferencesBloc>().add(VibratePrefEvent());
            });
      },
    )
```

The issue is as follow.

[image]

When I click on viration, the sound setting is unchecked.

So I am not getting whats is happening here.

Since I am now to flutter BLoC and I am learning. Can anyone help me out here what I am doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

If I use bloc like this `BlocSelector<AppPreferencesBloc, VibratePrefState, bool>()`...

```
BlocSelector<AppPreferencesBloc, VibratePrefState, bool>(
      selector: (state) {
        return state.vibrate;
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return _getListTile(
            title: Constants.vibrarion,
            subtitle: Constants.vibrarionSubtitle,
            leadingIcon: Icons.vibration,
            trailing: Checkbox(
              value: state,
              onChanged: (value) {},
            ),
            action: () {
              context.read<AppPreferencesBloc>().add(VibratePrefEvent());
            });
      },
    )
```

It is giving me following error.

```
'AppPreferencesBloc' doesn't conform to the bound 'StateStreamable<VibratePrefState>' of the type parameter 'B'. 
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'StateStreamable<VibratePrefState>'
```

The `VibratePrefState` class is sub class of `AppPreferencesState` class.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `selector`:

```dart
BlocSelector<AppPreferencesBloc, AppPreferencesState, bool>(
  selector: (state) {
    return (state is VibratePrefState) ? state.vibrate : true;
  },
```

As you can see, if the `state` is not `VibratePrefState` (which would be the case when you select the play sound option) it will return `true`, which make the vibration option selected.

To fix it, you have to return the current state of the vibration option when the `state` is not `VibratePrefState`.

```dart
BlocSelector<AppPreferencesBloc, AppPreferencesState, bool>(
  selector: (state) {
    return (state is VibratePrefState)
        ? state.vibrate
        : getTheCurrentStateOfVibrateSomehow();
  },
```

Alternatively, this would be simplier if you use [`BlocBuilder`](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts?id=blocbuilder). You can define the case where the bloc should rebuild:

```dart
BlocBuilder<AppPreferencesBloc, AppPreferencesState, bool>(
  buildWhen: (_, state) {
    return state is VibratePrefState;
  },
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion. But it is giving an error. I have edited the question.

Comment: You still need the check with `is VibratePrefState`. If it's true, return `state.vibrate`. If it's false, return the previous state. I'm not familiar with bloc but there has to be a way to get the previous state. See my edited answer.

Comment: Also, this would be easier if you use `BlocBuilder`. You can control when to build with `buildWhen`. I've added that to my answer